# How to use MongoDB $in in aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm querying my MongoDB collection of hotels, and I need to create a `$match` stage, where I only keep documents, which have at least one room, that matches each `$in`

A sample document in my collection:

```
{
  title: "Lorem ipsum",
  rooms: [
    {
       type: "shelter",
       spots: 2
    },
    {
       type: "box",
       spots: 1
    },
    {
       type: "house",
       spots: 5
    },
  ]
}
```

This $match stage works:

```
{
  "rooms.type": {
    $in: ["shelter"]
  }
  "rooms.type": {
    $in: ["box"]
  }
}
```

But I can't create an object with two identical keys in Javascript.
So I need to send it like this from my NodeJS API.
But how come this doesn't work?:

```
{
  $expr: {
    $or: [
      { $in: ["$rooms.type", ["shelter"]] },
      { $in: ["$rooms.type", ["box"]] }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly you can add an `$or` stage to create the conditions like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [
        {
          "rooms.type": {"$in": ["shelter","first","array"]}
        },
        {
          "rooms.type": {"$in": ["box","second","array"]}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

This query will returns documents which field `rooms.type` contains values that exists into one of the two arrays.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OB7cl_yJbzU)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That wasn't quite what I was looking for though. Maybe my questions wasn't clear enough. I have two seperate arrays where the `rooms.type` need to match the $in of both of them. So I can't add both into a single condition like you did.

Comment: Oh ok, I think now I've understood, I've updated the answer.

Comment: That was my first idea @WernfriedDomscheit (before the edit), but OP wants to match two separate arrays.